# how to serve multiple builds from one url with now ziet, to support angular i18n

Tags: angular, routes, vercel

I am using Now Zeit to serve my angular 9 application.

I want this website to use two different languages (en and zh) - the angular framework way to do i18n involves creating multiple builds, so my build folder after a complete rebuild of the app looks like this

- dist

  - en
  - zh

There are two builds.

Now I want to serve this with Now Zeit. So far I have set up Now Zeit to integrate with my GitLab project. My settings look like this:

- Framework Preset: Angular
- Build Command: ng build
- Output Directory: dist/en
- Development Directory: ng serve

This is serving the the english build of the website.

BUT, what I want is this:

- path: '/', redirectsTo: '/en/'
- path: '/en/, serves: '/dist/en/'
- path: '/zh/, serves: '/dist/zh/'

How can I achieve this with Now Ziet, while keeping my gitlab integration if possible. TIA.

#### Bonus points

If you could also help me with a problem I am having where my angular routes return a 404, i.e. anything but '/' returns a 404, because the angular app handles the routing, Now Zeit does not know to send requests to the build because it doesn't have these routes set up.

TIA

Comment: You want to navigate to yoursite.com/en and have the site in english, if you navigate to .../zh you want the site in another language, right?

Comment: Yes @jascoposciampi

Comment: Have a look at this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ixpjfv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts is not working because stackblitz doesn't allow to load custom json but if you do a console.log in the ngOnInit you will see the language catched. Is that what are you lookin' for?

Comment: Plus, I'm using this exact code on a project that's working. If you need some data: https://github.com/JacopoSciampi/core-cartoon/tree/feature/init-stuff/client

Comment: You are using ngx-translate not angular i18n. This creates one single build and provides different a json object depending on the local. I am looking for serving two different builds - angular i18n creates a separate build for each language.